# Salesforce Metadata API CustomField Set Field Level Security

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a custom field on the Leads object using the metadata api. More specifically using the jsforce node module.

I can create the field just fine, but I can't query it after it's created. I have searched for a way to set field level permissions on the field using the API but I haven't found anything.

Is there a way to set field level security on a newly created custom field? Or do I have to go into the Salesforce UI to do it?

This post says that I probably need to do it from the UI.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000UVldQAG

But if thats the case, what good is the API then?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the field level security using the metadata API. When you create a field, send the field level permission in Admin Profile type metadata.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>ObjectName__c.Field__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Comment: I am using the jsforce node module and it keeps giving me an unexpected error. I am not sure if the node module supports this.